# Software / System Handover Template - Are there any good examples out there?

Tags: templates, documentation, release

I'm required to provide a handover to our content editors for the update corporate website I've just released.  Apparently a training session with notes isn't sufficient.  Fair enough.

So more dreaded documentation looms.  After a fairly brief trawl over Google, I'm unable to find any relevant and usable template to use as the basis of a website or web application handover.  The most useful list of items I've found that should appear in such a document were on Experts Exchange (the enemy):

1. System overview, general introduction
2. processes and interdepartmental process flow
3. system configuration, setup and dependencies
4. technical requirements, features and limitations
5. support process
6. escalation lists and contact information for relevant parties for troubleshooting

This is a good basis to work from - I can "dumb it down" for users who will only be making content changes to the site, but does anyone know of a good standard template available in the cloud?  Is there more that should be added to this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of available templates, per se, but see also this question: [What are the core elements to include in Support Documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205374/what-are-the-core-elements-to-include-in-support-documentation)

Comment: Thanks.  That stuff will be useful.  Looks like October's the month for everyone to do their support documentation...